# C# custom error if string crashes

Tags: c#, mysql, string

So i have the following string in c# that returns a mysql query.

```
string id = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

The problem is that if the indput to this string is not valid it crashes the app. This should not crash the app but show this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Your key (" + KeyNr + ") was invalid or not active. \nPlease check if it is the correct key or you need to buy another month.", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Tried with try and catch with no luck. can someone help?

some of my tries:

```
try
{
   string id = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Your key (" + KeyNr + ") was invalid or not active. \nPlease check if it is the correct key or you need to buy another month.", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

and

```
try
{
   string id = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
catch (catch (MySqlException))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Your key (" + KeyNr + ") was invalid or not active. \nPlease check if it is the correct key or you need to buy another month.", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

all gives me:

```
Error   2   The name 'id' does not exist in the current context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this piece of code:

```
string id = string.Empty;

try
{
   id = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your key (" + KeyNr + ") was invalid or not active. \nPlease check if it is the correct key or you need to buy another month.", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

You can even catch it to more specific Exception instead of having generic `Exception`.

Comment: did that but it gives me Error 2 The name 'id' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 4):

Without solving it for you, you need to store and check the result of `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` before assuming it executes and can be transformed into a string.

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (/* result is valid */){
  id = result.ToString();
} else {
  MessageBox.Show(/* message */);
}
```

Stray away from exception checking whenever possible as using them is unnecessarily heavy on performance and is (in a lot of ways) a lazy way of skipping good old-fashioned checking.

Comment: @DmitryVyakhirev: Good call, added.